# How to Not Display Tab Title in JtabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

How to not display tab title in Jtabbedpane?
how to manage multiple overhand jpanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `null` for the title text when you insert the tab. For example:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab(null, new JPanel());
```

Alternatively, call [`setTitleAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTitleAt%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) to set the title of a specific tab to `null`:

```
tabbedPane.setTitleAt(1, null);
```